# possible upgrades for merida speeder 200

Tags: derailleur-rear

I have a Speeder 200. (2015). I want to upgrade it's rear derailleur, my problem is I am unsatisfied with its performance. (it is a Tiagra with 9 speed at the moment). If i replace it with a 105 (9 speed) should I replace the other components(cassette, chain, front derailleur etc.) as well? Or can i replace with a ultegra?(does a 9 speed exists) Should I buy a groupset?  haven't tried an upgrade before.

edit: I have been using it for around 400 kilometers, components are still fine, but I was never happy with that Tiagra. I have some problems with shifting, if speed is >20km/h it does not shift properly. I have taken my bike to Merida service twice, I don't think there is a cabling or another problem. It seems OK, but on road i dont like its poor shifting. For example I change it 6th to 7th, after a few cycles I hear a mechanical sound and it decides to change, not on time.

I had another bike with Deore rear derailleur before, never had an issue like this.

Comment: How much distance is on the bike/how far have you ridden it?  At 2000 km you'd be looking at a new chain anyway.

Comment: you won't *find* 9sp 105. I'd also be surprised if you could find 9sp Ultegra, but try searching for 6500 components (which was 9sp Ultegra).

Comment: I'm guessing you need to find a different shop to adjust it or adjust it yourself. If its been in a crash you may have bent the derailleur or something, but modern Tiagra should be very good.

Comment: I'm with @Batman here. something is probably adjusted wrong. It may not even need to be a crash. Simply having your bike fall over on the drive side can be enough to bend the derailleur hanger. Bad cable routing can also cause problems with how well shifting works.  Better to diagnose the problem than spend money on parts that won't fix the issue anyway.

Comment: Been using 9sp Tiagra for ages and while it is not the best derailleur in the world, it does its job without any hassle and is pretty reliable. All you need is to adjust it properly, which is supposed to be a routine operation anyway. Changing it to 105 (they are not fully compatible anyway) won't change anything. The issue seems to be either wit the cables themselves, or merely with the adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

All Shimano road derailleurs (2400, Claris, Tiagra, 105, Ultegra, DuraAce) made for 7-10 speeds are compatible with eachother. The amount that the derailleur moves is determined by the shifter.  With 11 speed they changed things up, so as long as the derailleur you chose was designed to work with 7-10 speeds you should be fine. For mountain derailleurs (Acera, Alivio, Deore) 7-9 speed derailleurs are compatible with the 7-10 road groupsets.

A 9 speed Ultegra or even DuraAce can be found at 9 speeds if you find old enough equipment, but all current 105, Ultegra, and DuraAce are 11 speed and will therefore not be compatible with your current 9 speed setup.  If you want to find a 105  9 or 10 speed derailleur, it won't be the current model, although the 10 speed 105 (5700), Ultegra (6700), or DuraAce (7900) is still readily available as a replacement part.

As an aside, are you sure that upgrading the derailleur will really fix your problem? What kind of problems are you having with the Tiagra? Could it be an adjustment or bad cabling that's causing your shifting problems?  Is your cassette or chain worn? 9 speed Tiagra is older equipment and it's possible that your chain or cassette are at the point where they should be replaced. I have 2400 (8 speed) level equipment, and find that it shifts quite well as long as the adjustment is good, and I usually don't need to adjust it very often.

Comment: This is wrong. 7-10 speed road and 7-9 speed mountain have same cable pull. 10 speed mountain is different (but the same as 11 speed road), and wont work with 10 speed road shifters.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Batman, I wasn't completely sure on which was compatible. I'll correct it in the answer so there's no confusion for people who don't read the comments.